# IBM MQ classes for JMS - locked when sending message

Tags: ibm-mq

Recently I started getting the following problem which results in messages not being delivered to:

```
"PollThread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f0a2cf86000 nid=0x76b8 in Object.wait() [0x00007f09eb6bf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.checkUsable(RemoteHconn.java:2121)
        - locked <0x000000048f040a10> (a com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn$ReconnectMutex)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.enterCall(RemoteHconn.java:1787)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteHconn.enterCall(RemoteHconn.java:1764)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiPutMessageWithProps(RemoteFAP.java:7804)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiPut(RemoteFAP.java:7254)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiPut(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:496)
        at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiPut(ESEJMQI.java:385)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.sendInternal(WMQMessageProducer.java:812)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer$ProducerShadow.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:531)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageProducer.send(WMQMessageProducer.java:1178)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.sendMessage(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:927)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send_(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:783)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageProducerImpl.send(JmsMessageProducerImpl.java:446)
```

Entire client application is unresponsive. How do I troubleshoot this type of problems with IBM MQ classes for JMS? Is it connection setup problems? There are no error in MQ log file. MQ version is 7.5.2. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The lock is being held on the ReconnectMutex meaning that a reconnection to the queue manager is currently in progress and so waits until it is notified that the reconnection has been successful. Is there another thread that looks like it is attempting to reconnect to the queue manager and is not moving? Do you know if the queue manager is up and running at this time?

Comment: The queue manager is up and running. From application thread dump it looks like that is the only thread waiting however I'm not sure how to check it.

Comment: Do you see any MQ thread doing a connect? or in a wait on a socket? If you could paste your thread dump somewhere I might be able to help.